# Laravel inserting 0 in non-nullable fields and no default value

Tags: php, laravel

I have this strange problem only in one project.
Currently it is possible to execute this code and Laravel translates to the following SQL:

```
 $elTicket = documentos_venta::create([
      
    ]);
```

SQL:

```
 insert into `documentos_ventas` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?) ["2021-05-13 13:42:14","2021-05-13 13:42:14"]
```

Results in:
SQL statement result
[image: SQL statement result]

Table:
[image: Table description]

The problem with this is that it is not respecting the non-nullable fields in the database table
and it is automatically filling the non-nullable integers with 0 and the varchar with null.
Occurs with any insert of a model within the project.

Forget to mention that executing the sql statement in mariaDB fails as expected

Comment: That is very strange. It should throw a not null constraint violation sql error. Are you positive it translates into that sql query? Maybe there's a mutator overriding those fields if they are null. Try adding the following in your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot()` method: `\DB::listen(function ($query) { debug([$query->sql, $query->bindings, $query->time]); });`. Then do the query and check your laravel logs.

Comment: Yes, it is very rare. Try a new project and it works fine.
I don't know what's going on with this one.
Yes, that way I got the generated sql

Comment: Check the `documentos_venta` model. Is there a function named something like `setSucursalAttribute($value)` ?, or maybe a `creating`, `updating` or `saving` event listeners defined?

Comment: @IGP
No, the model is correct.
Also the problem is in any model of the project

Comment: Try the `\DB::listen` thing. It will show the exact queries with the bindings run against your database.

Comment: @IGP.
Yes, this is how I got the SQL that is in the example.
In AppServiceProvider I have:
 DB::listen(function ($query) {
            Log::info(
                $query->sql,
                $query->bindings,
                $query->time
            );
        });

Comment: What if you run that query as raw as you can with `DB::insert`? Same problem?

Comment: @IGP 
With DB :: Insert the exact same thing happens.
I am 100% sure that a month ago this was working correctly.

Comment: Then maybe something is up at the database level. When you said you execute the statement in mariaDB, you meant by using HeidiSQL?

Comment: @IGP
If I execute the SQL statement with HeidiSQL, DBeaver or even with the mariaDB console it fails as expected.

[code]MariaDB [pkglogger]> INSERT INTO documentos_ventas (created_at,sucursal) values ('2020-01-01 00:00:00',1); 
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'tipo_comprobante' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @IGP.
Solved
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.
Inside config / database.php
The configuration for the MYSQL connection was incorrect

Incorrect:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

The strict value is false, it must be true.
I don't know why is set to false

Comment: It would be set to false by default to be compatible with the vast majority of existing MySQL installations out there (though strict is better in any case). Have you recently upgraded or changed the database you are using at all?

Comment: I just checked other projects and the strict value is true.

This project is made in laravel 7, it started with php 7.x and some time ago it updated to php 8.0 but it is still in laravel 7.

Edit: Change the strict value in another project and effectively if it is set to false this problem occurs

Comment: @Jason 
I forgot to tag you

Comment: From the MYSQL docs: *If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit default value for the column data type* and *For numeric types, the default is 0*

Comment: @Jason
Yes, that was the mistake.
I couldn't find it because I had no idea that it was set to false.